# Order of a subgroup $H$ and $\langle H,b\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, and $H$ a subgroup. Suppose $H$ contains an element $a$ where there is some $b \in G$ with $a \in \langle b \rangle$ and $|b|/|a| = p$, some prime $p$. Do we necessarily have $[\langle H,b\rangle : H] = 1 \text{ or } p$ ?

Note I can apply something similar to second isomorphism to establish: $| H\langle b \rangle | / |H|$ divides $p$, but here $H\langle b\rangle \subset \langle H , b\rangle$, so that didn't quite get me there.

Also, do we have some generalities to the order of $\langle H,x\rangle$ for any $x\in G$? Thanks for the inputs!

Edited: Added condition $a \in \langle b \rangle$

Comment: The step you are missing is: $G$ is abelian, so $H\langle b\rangle=\langle H, b\rangle$. So you're fine.

Comment: Oh my @user1729, yes! I overlooked that detail! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, great. I'll make my comment into an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically there. The step you are missing is: $G$ is abelian, so $H\langle b\rangle=\langle H, b\rangle$.